# Rails: uninitialized constant MODEL_NAME

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailman

I have a ruby on rails script that I run by issuing the command: sudo ruby script/mailman_server The contents of this file are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"
require "mailman"
require "rb-inotify"
require "#{File.dirname __FILE__}/../config/environment"

Mailman.config.maildir = '/var/mail'

Mailman::Application.run do
    default do
        begin
            # call a model
            Bin.receive_mail(message)
        end
    end
end
```

I get an error saying:

```
E, [2013-03-15T02:06:39.555346 #6351] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Bin
/var/www/beebin/script/mailman_server:14
```

Bin is a model and receive_mail() is a function in that model. Why can't my script see the model?

I feel like the rails environment isn't loading properly. What am I missing from the code or what is the best way to start the app?

Comment: Hello! Can you call method from console ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it resolves your problem, but this is a prettier syntax

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment')
```

To be sure your environment is loaded, try to do `Bin` just after your require.

Comment: I have put `b=Bin.all` right after the requires and it doesn't give me an error on that line. However I still get an error on line 14 which is `Bin.receive_mail(message)`.